# How does the brain store information?

Tags: bioinformatics, brain, information

In all electronic devices with the possibility of saving there are tiny magnets that can store your data by the state they are in. In general, there has to be something changed to store information and independent observer should be (theoretically) able to read all the stored information just from one state of brain.

I think keeping some signal in circuit would be really nutrition expensive (through the ion pumps that create the electro-chemical gradients).

So how does a brain store the information?

Comment: @AliceD I deliberetaly chose two different words to suggest some different type of storing, even though I see no difference since brain seems to be a bunch of neurons. The only meaning of just "neurons" version I can imagine is as question how do nutritions get to the right neurons and that I think is pretty clear.

Comment: Let me clarify: Neurons as units of the brain store information e.g. by LTP. This single-neuron-level learning in e.g. hippocampus has been well-investigated. The brain is yes, a 'bunch of neurons' but information storage at the brain level is highly complicated. In its simplest form the hippocampus stores info for ~24h whereafter it is stored in widespread areas in the cortex. How it is retrieved from there is pretty complex and pretty unknown afaik. The pitch of the answer to the title (Basic electrophysiology) is hence completely different from your concluding sentence (Cognitive Sciences)

Comment: I still don't understand the meaning of the question only with neurons, but OK, I'm going to rewrite it.

Comment: Probably - does @WYSIWYG 's linked question answers yours? It does seem an exact duplicate to me.

Comment: @AliceD I think yes. I really like the idea of connecting your sensations to recieve every information. Only thing I think is different is my circuit or state dilema with which I'm still not sure. Does LTP and LTD work like 0 and 1 state for neuron or are there some circuits switched to long-term synapse which allows the signal come out only if some neuron has "flipped the switch" by some signal from the outside?